# PowerShell Skype for Business server side filtering on variable

Tags: powershell, skype-for-business

Just a quick one. Anyone know why server side filtering doesn't appear to work for lineuri when using a variable?

```
$lineuri = 56660
Get-CsUser -Filter { lineuri -like "*$lineuri" }
```

I get nothing.

```
Get-CsUser -Filter { lineuri -like "*56660" }
```

Gives me the results I'd expect to see.

I have 7000 users here, I can't afford to keep using where all the time.

Thanks

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work for me either. Same results, i.e. nothing

Comment: @jrider That's not true at all.  `$()` is a subexpression.  You do not need that to utilize string expansion.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 You are right. My bad on the answer. I'll remove the comment.

Comment: @jrider If he had variable-valid characters next to it, that would be true, but it would be more accurate to use `${}` variable delimiters instead (such as `"$mystr:"` needs to be `"${mystr}:"` to avoid being a scope/drive modifier)

Answer (score 2):

Oh, oh, oh!

Fixed it.

```
$lineuri = 56660
Get-CsUser -Filter "lineuri -like '*$lineuri'"
```

Some times it takes a fresh mind to help you focus. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Ah, there ya go. Simple syntax :) nice job

Comment: Avoid using scriptblocks for filters.  They get converted using `.ToString()` anyways so you're adding a layer for no gain.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you get that dollar sign in there for the variable

```
$lineuri = 56660
Get-CsUser -Filter "lineuri -like *$lineuri"
```

If for some reason that doesn't work, maybe try this

```
$lineuri = *56660
Get-CsUser -Filter "lineuri -like $lineuri"
```

Last but not least

```
$lineuri = *56660
Get-CsUser -Filter "lineuri -like $($lineuri)"
```

Since you are running this on a remote machine, you could also give this a shot (but it may have the same result of not working)

```
Invoke-Command -Computername "ComputerNameHere" -Scriptblock { $lineuri = *56660;Get-CsUser -Filter "lineuri -like $lineuri)" }
```

Comment: Ah sorry, a typo on the original question. Have resolved.

Neither scenario plays out as I'd hoped.

Is it worth mentioning I'm using a remote PS Session to perform these Skype tasks?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to mention that in your post. You could also try out the `Invoke-Command` function with this code if you are getting this information from a remote machine. I've added an example to my post.